# Styling Wordpress Widgets Horizontally

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I’m currently working on putting together a child theme off of the new [Twenty Twelve](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/twentytwelve) Wordpress website. The site has a fluid/liquid structure for its responsiveness (using percentages as opposed to fixed widths in pixels - which would relate to how I may have to style my widgets).

At the top of my template I would like to include a widgetized area where the user/admin can drag and drop items from the available widgets in the list provided.

Ideally, as the design and layout of the site for this section is on a horizontal plane, three widgets would visually look nice in terms of space.

However, if the user would like to add more, I take it that I would need to work with PHP or JavaScript to calculate if there is a certain amount of divs/classes/ids within a section tag for example, change the CSS widths from 33.33% (3 widgets) to 25% (4 widgets) or 50% is there is two etc. ?

How would I be able to accommodate an equally spaced width for each widget and place them next to each other?

Comment: please don't remove your original question - people need to see what the question was in order for your selected "best answer" to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little messy, but here's a start:

```
<?php
$widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
$percentage = !empty($widgets['header-widget-area']) ? floor(100/count($widgets['header-widget-area'])) : 100;
?>
<style type="text/css">
hgroup .widget{
    width:<?php echo $percentage; ?>% !important;
    float:left;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Try dropping it either at the very top or very bottom of your header.php file. If that doesn't work, a link to the live or testing version would also help.

Comment: You can try changing `floor(100/count($widgets['header-widget-area']))` to just `100/count($widgets['header-widget-area'])`, since decimals are honored by CSS when used in percentages. Otherwise, I would just target the widgets directly with CSS to apply any additional rules as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Bootstrap Grid View. 
Complete details can be found [HERE](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic).

The theory is, Bootstrap grid is having 12 columns by default. 
If you want 3 columns in a row, you'll divide 12 by 4.  
It will produce 3 columns in a row. You can see example on Bootstrap Grid Link.